# Loop through a vector in ngspice

Tags: transistors, spice

ngspice is not capable of performing a DC analysis while sweeping transistor length. I'm trying to do a workaround by creating a vector, looping through it, and altering `@m1[l]`

Here's a minimal working code:

```
VA 4 2 DC 0
VSBN 0 3 DC 0
VGSN 1 0 DC 1
VDSN 4 0 DC 1
M1 2 1 0 3 nmos w=200n l=45n

.control
compose length start=100n stop=500n step=1n
foreach l length <-- ??? not sure about this
  alter @m1[l] l <-- ??? not sure about this, too
  dc VGSN 0 1 1m
end
.endc
```

Is there some way to loop through a vector in ngspice?

Answer (score 2):

I use LTSpice, so I have no experience of this in ngspice and you may have already seen this, but have you had a look at p.266 and p.321 of the [manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf)?

It looks quite similar to your code above. The other option is usng LTSpice, in which this is certainly possible.
Here is an LTSpice netlist in which the length of a monolithic NMOS is swept from 1nm to 2000nm (All other values default)

```
* C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceIV\MOSFET param test 2.asc
V1 +V 0 5 Rser=0
R1 +V N001 1K
R2 N004 0 1m
R3 +V N003 500k
R4 N003 0 500k
M1 N001 N003 N004 N002 OLIMOS
R5 N002 0 1m
.model NMOS NMOS
.model PMOS PMOS
.lib C:\PROGRA~1\LTC\LTSPIC~1\lib\cmp\standard.mos
.step NMOS OLIMOS(L) 1n 2000n 100n
.model OLIMOS NMOS(KP=2e-5)
.op
.backanno
.end
```